# Batch - Replace Nth Character of variable

Tags: batch-file, variables, replace, substitution

I've been stuck trying to replace `n`th character from a variable. Here is an example.

```
String: This Will Be A 230 Bytes String

Input : 1st char, change to char 5 
       (the variable and character to change is hardcoded, so you can ignore it)

Output: 5his Will Be A 230 Bytes String
```

I couldn't figure out how to do this. Here is what I have tried.

```
set remaining=237-%aircraft1Loc%
set aircraft1LocB=%aircraft1Loc%-1
call set LowTrack=%OrgLowTrack:~0,%
call set LowTrack=%%OrgLowTrack:~0,%aircraft1LocB%%%5 %%OrgLowTrack,%aircraft1Loc%,%remaining%%
```

This is the `%OrgLowTrack%`

```````
                             {0C}+{#}                                                `.:////////::--.`     ``.....``````                      ``.``  ``         ````                                             ```     ``..```
```````

- LowTrack should now contain the replaced string.
- Aircraft1Loc defaults to 231 and reduces 1 everytime the above script runs(the `set /a var-=1` is not shown here-)
- remaining is 237 - aircraft1Loc
- aircraft1LocB is aircraft1Loc - 1

The result should be something like

```
Original: XXXXXXXX(String shortened)
Output  : XXXXXXX5
2nd out : XXXXX5XX - This occurs when the snippet is run again
```

But my snippet outputs:

```
Original: XXXXXXXX
Output  : XXXXXXXX5 OrgLowTrack,,237 -
2nd out : XXXXXXXX5 OrgLowTrack,,237
```

Comment: `Set "string=This Will Be A 230 Bytes String"` and `Set "string=5%string:~1%"` should do what you want.

Comment: @LotPings I get this: `5This Will Be....`

Comment: Are you trying this in a batch or from cmd line? Are Extensions enabled?

Comment: @LotPings From a batch file with extensions enabled

Comment: Please post the `OrgLowTrack` as text rather than as image!

Comment: @aschipfl Noted. Change will be made within a day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrote the batch completely (needed a sub for strLen):

```
:: Q:\Test\2017\07\09\SO_44995458.cmd
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set "string=This Will Be A 230 Bytes String"

Call :strLen string len

For /L %%i in (%len%,-1,0) Do (
  Echo !string:~0,%%i!_!string:~%%i!
)

Goto :Eof
:strLen string len
:: returns the length of a string
:: string [in]  - variable name containing the string being measured for length
:: len    [out] - variable to be used to return the string length
:$source http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringOperations.php#Function.strLen
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set "str=A!%~1!"
set "len=0"
for /L %%A in (12,-1,0) do (set /a "len|=1<<%%A"
  for %%B in (!len!) do if "!str:~%%B,1!"=="" set /a "len&=~1<<%%A"
)
ENDLOCAL & IF "%~2" NEQ "" SET /a %~2=%len%
EXIT /b
```

Comment: So.. I want the output to be `XXXX5`, next round: `XXX5X`, so do I changed `~1` to `~-1`?

Comment: That will return only the last char from string. See the syntax of set with `set /?` or visit http://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Comment: I see I see. Then how can I produce the result I wanted?

Comment: Stlll not clear to me, what you want to achieve. Added a line to change the last char to the batch

Comment: So I want the script to output XXXXX, XXXX5, and then XXX5X, XX5XX, X5XXX, 5XXXX, then XXXXX

Comment: Your title says `replace` but now it's output? That are different things. See changed batch.

Comment: My fault. I mean to say replace the variable, but I didn't notice I also requested I want the output